# Objective-c app can't read sql database

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, c, sqlite

so the fight with this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_7_Application) goes on.

I made my own database(techbase.sql) and inserted two people into it - one of them with name of marian, adress menda and phone 112.
This application should log out in text fields: name, adress and phone from database when I input persons name into name field.

Saving properties into new database created "dynamically" in app works. But reading from db at start of the app doesn't.
What may be the problem? Have i specified name of db wrong? Or maybe the database table is made wrong?
Here is my project http://speedy.sh/D6hau/techtopiatut-3.zip if you would like to look in.

Thanks you in advance!

Just in case if this is confusing I will write easier:

-techbase.sql has two people in it

-cant log out their phone and adress by putting in name when I start app(like cant read db or something)

-can save and then log out but I want to read from pre-maid db. Not from table made in app.

Comment: Code looks good.  Add some breakpoints, examine some variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your .sql database on the Xcode files list and then, in the right side, check that the Target Memership is correct (your target should be checked).

Comment: His project doesn't use a "pre-packed" database file; if it doesn't exist the code creates it and adds the tables.  Look at the code.

Comment: Is it done right? http://i.imgur.com/JHOZTwg.png
It's still not working after I checked that box

Comment: Yes, exactly trojan - but for some reason it always creates new db. And I want to use the one I pre-packed.

Comment: I made a library that manages SQL databases in a very easy way, give it a shot https://github.com/AlvaroFranco/AFSQLManager